# copy spreadsheet and his script to a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an original spreadsheet that contains some functions in the script.
When I make a copy of that file I want to copy also the script not only the file

I use this line of code, but it copies only the file not the file+scripr

```
 var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderID);
 DriveApp.getFileById("..........").makeCopy("New Name ",destFolder);
```

Comment: It may not move the script to a folder without Drive API.  In that case it will probably be left in the root.  You can use Drive API update to move it to the destination folder.

Comment: I think that in the case of `makeCopy`, when the Spreadsheet includes Google Apps Script project as the container-bound script and that is copied by `makeCopy`, the copied Spreadsheet has the copied container-bound script. So, I cannot understand `I use this line of code, but it copies only the file not the file+scripr`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?